# Java: how do I create a program that encrypts lines by swapping pairs of characters?

Tags: java, encryption

I'm looking for a simplistic way of coding a program that encrypts lines by swapping pairs of characters, and these characters are input by the user. So for example if you wrote any of these:

```
Original line         Encrypted line
abcdef                badcfe
The quick brown fox   hT euqci krbwo nofx
abc                   bac
```

I have only ever been able to accomplish simple encryption such as this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Encryption
{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a line");
    String line = kb.nextLine();
    String encrypted="";
    for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        if (c == 'a')
            encrypted += 'e';
        else if (c == 'e')
            encrypted += 'a';
        else 
            encrypted += c;
    }
    System.out.println(encrypted);
}
```

Can this be modified to perform the swapping pairs encryption?

Comment: By "encryption" do you mean you would like to be able to decrypt back to the original?  That would be significantly harder.

Comment: No, I'm only looking to be able to put in the characters, and have the encryption shown. It doesn't need to be reversed.

Comment: It's for an exercise in my textbook. So it doesn't serve me any Real purpose, but is more a learning tool.

Comment: There are people who posted a solution, but my advise is to ignore theirs and do your own. If you do not learn to be able to do a simple task as this, you won't be able to do more complex tasks. If this was homework, then you are setting yourself up to fail the next examn.

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a line");
        String line = kb.nextLine();

        String encrypted = encriptInput(line);

        System.out.println(encrypted);
    }

    private static String encriptInput(String line) {

        String[] splitedChars = line.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
        String outPut = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < splitedChars.length; i++) {

            outPut = splitedChars[i].trim().length() < 2?outPut+splitedChars[i]:outPut+splitedChars[i].charAt(1)+splitedChars[i].charAt(0);
        }

        return outPut;
    }
}
```